# Caesar Cipher; Debug Assertion Failed

Tags: c

I have written code to do a Caesar Shift Cipher taking the input from a file called "input.txt" and writing the output to a file called "output.txt". It technically works fine; the output comes out almost perfectly, but when I run it I get a `Debug Assertion Failed` message regarding `Line 56` which is the line that closes the output file. The error also says: Expression: `(unsigned)(c+1) <= 256`. Here is my code:

```
void cipher(char input[], int key);

int main()
{

    int i, key=0;
    char c, input[MAX];
    FILE *file1;
    file1 = fopen("input.txt","r");

    printf("Enter the key: ");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    getchar();

    for(i=0;(c=getc(file1))!=EOF && i<MAX;i++)
        input[i]=c;
    fclose(file1);
    cipher(input, key);
    return 0;
}

void cipher(char input[], int key)
{
    int length = strlen(input)-1;
    int i;
    char c;
    FILE *file2;
    file2 = fopen("output.txt","w");
    for (i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(input[i]))
        {
            c = (toupper(input[i]) - 'A'+key) % 26 + 'A';
            fprintf(file2, "%c", c);
        }
        else if (input[i]==' ')
            fprintf(file2, "\n");
    }

    fclose(file2);
}
```

Oh, and a less pressing issue, but when the code spits out the input, if the input changes lines, like "input text\n here" then when it does the cipher for "text" and "here", it puts them together instead of putting them on separate lines like it's supposed to. If anyone knows why that is and could help me out I would appreciate it, but the main thing is that error.

Comment: " I'm still fairly new to the site and I haven't quite figured out how to properly format the code without it exploding." Select your block of code and hit the `{}` button. See also http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: if `input[i]=='\n'` then you write nothing, hence the "less pressing issue"

Comment: Is there more code that you haven't shared? Could there be some function or process testing your output that is doing the assert?

Comment: That's only 40-some lines of code. What's missing?

Comment: I know what happened. When I was fiddling with it trying to get it to accept my code, I removed my includes and most of the white space that my instructor requires. That makes up for the rest of the lines. The error that I talked about points to the line 'fclose(file2);' if that helps any.

Comment: But no, that's it. Other than the includes that is all of the code. Like I said, it works, it just gives me that error. And Keith, thanks. Your fix worked wonders.

Comment: No it doesn't work fine. For one, it eats the last character of the file (what's with `strlen(input)-1`)? For two, you are not terminating your string with the null character.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here.

```
char c, /* ... */;
for(i=0;(c=getc(file1))!=EOF && i<MAX;i++)
    input[i]=c;
```

This is wrong. `getc` returns an `int`, so c should also be an `int`. The reason is that there are two types of return values for `getc`:

1. A positive value, which can be represented as an **unsigned char**.
2. A negative value, which indicates an error.

If you convert straight to `char`, there is no way to check for errors. `char` might be signed or unsigned. If it's unsigned, then `(c=getc(file1))` will end up being a positive number, which can't possibly compare equal to `EOF`. Hence, your loop doesn't end when `EOF` is encountered. If your `char` is signed, then your program might malfunction in other strange ways, such as terminating the loop *too early*, or segfaulting on some machines.

**This goes for all standard C functions! Make sure you check return values BEFORE converting them!** That includes `scanf`.

`<ctype.h>` is where you get your `isalpha` and `toupper` functions from.

> **7.4 Character handling**
>
> 1 The header  declares several functions useful for
>   classifying and mapping characters.198) In all cases the argument is
>   an **int**, the value of which shall be representable as an **unsigned char**
>   or shall equal the value of the macro EOF. If the argument has any
>   other value, the behavior is undefined.

It seems to me like you may be invoking undefined behaviour, by passing possibly negative values into `isupper`.

Comment: Hmm, alright. That makes sense, but even if I change C to an int I still get an error. Do I need to cast c after changing into an integer somewhere?

Comment: `int c = getchar(); char d = c; if (isalpha((unsigned char) d)) { ... }`

Comment: Store `int` return values in `int` variables. Pass `unsigned char` values when an `unsigned char` value is expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSVC, please be aware that the debug CRT checks if the parameter passed to isalpha is in the range `EOF` or `0..0xff` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt82b8z8(v=vs.100).aspx)). In your code you are calling `isalpha(input[i])` with `input` being a `char` array. Since `isalpha` requires an `int` you might end up calling `isalpha` with values outside the allowed range. You should change your call to `isalpha((unsigned char)input[i])`.

I'ld also change the calls to `toupper` accordingly.

And as `undefined behaviour` already said you must store the result of `getc` in an `int` variable, compare it to `EOF` and then convert it to a `char` and store it. After converting it to a `char` you can't compare it to `EOF` anymore (`EOF` is an `int` value which is not representable as a `char`).